# How to plot the graph from lambda stream to node.js client side

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am working in plotting the live graph from amazon dynamo db using node.js. I am getting  live data from lambda stream when inserting the data in dynamo db.
I need to plot graph using lambda stream data.
Help me to plot graph and how to pass lambda stream data to client side graph  using node.js

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be sending data from Aws IoT to Elasticsearch then show it live using kibana. Kibana offers you a great set of graphs to plot your data.

Here is a link that would help you to do that:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/analyze-device-generated-data-with-aws-iot-and-amazon-elasticsearch-service/